# Are there significant risks of using chrome driver

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, anaconda, selenium-chromedriver, spyder

I need to use chrome driver to automate web navigation using selenium.

However, the work computer that I use did not like it, I had to bypass a couple of security blocks. When I dowloaded chrome driver I tried to run it in the cmd terminal which threw up a link and a recommendation that I should read its contents. the link was the following:

https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations

The link's web page contained a series of warnings about running chrome driver on a computer that has privileged access to information. My computer happens to have just that.

I need to find a way of automating website navigation with or without chrome driver, what should I do??

Comment: What do you mean "website navigation"? What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because it can do stuff like access websites that you might not want to access, either because its private data or because its a site that you arent allowed to access by law. Pretty sure that, as long as you dont run scripts from others, and know what you are doing yourself you arent taking a risk. The main problem is, that you might not be able to cancel it anymore if it runs once. If you rather do it in another way, you can use the geckodriver from firefox, i have not had such a warning yet but i assume the risk is the same